# How to print full qualified packages in gradles output?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I'm using gradle to build and test my Java Application. I use Spring Tool Suite and Spring Boot.

When I look at the console output after executing the gradle task "test" I see shortened full qualified package names.

How can I tell Spring Boot or Gradle to output fully qualified package names and print them unshortened?

For example I want to see

**org.springframework.context.annotation.** AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

instead of

**s.c.a.** AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the matter of gradle. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging) You can find the whole chapter dedicated to spring-boot logger configuration. You just need to configure (via e.g. `logback.xml`) the underlying log system.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a perfect starting point. At the end I found this http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord and this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic.xml and withit I think I want to override CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN of the second file. So I'm going to formulate my question new: "Can I do that in application.properties?" In my opinion that would be cleaner that creating a whole new configuration file, because then I'd have to track changes in GIT-file for each project

Comment: This seems to be another question. If this one is answered accept it and ask another question regarding `application.properties`.